# Is there an ansible command to configure a vmware host to synchronize time with the host?

Tags: ansible, vmware

I've been searching the docs for a bit, but is there a way in ansible - either the rest api or the built-in api - for vcenter to configure a host that has vmware tools installed to synchronize its time with the host?

[image: option I need set]